# Android application publish

Tags: android

i am using License Verification Library for my paid Android application.
so is there any necessity to add eula(End User License Agreement) to my application?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to provide an EULA if you don't want to. This is optional, and completely upto you. By using the LVL, you aren't forced to provide an EULA with your app.

Answer (score 0):

No, EULA is not mandatory. Please read this [Publishing Checklist for Google Play](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html)